# how can I clear specific streamlit cache?

Tags: python, caching, streamlit

I run `streamlit` script with a few caches.

When I use the following code it clears all the caches:

```
from streamlit import caching

caching.clear_cache()
```

I would like to clear only a specific cache. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn’t currently (easily) doable.

This is an optional solution that can be applied to some cases:

You can use the `allow_output_mutation` option:

```
import streamlit as st

@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)
def mutable_cache():
    return some_list

mutable_object = mutable_cache()

if st.button("Clear history cache"):
    mutable_object.clear()
```

I wrote the returned cached object as list but you can use other object types as well (then you have to replace the `clear` method which is specific to lists).

For more info please look on [the answers I got in the streamlit community forum](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/how-can-i-clear-a-specific-cache-only/1963)

Answer (score 1):

FYI: Streamlit is current proposing a way to clean cache on given elements (still in experimental mode though):

https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/experimental-cache-primitives#clear-memo-and-singleton-caches-procedurally

```py
@st.experimental_memo
def square(x):
    return x**2

if st.button("Clear Square"):
    # Clear square's memoized values:
    square.clear()

if st.button("Clear All"):
    # Clear values from *all* memoized functions:
    st.experimental_memo.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Streamlit has a current method that will do this now. https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/performance/st.cache_data

Scroll down to the section that says "A cached function's cache can be procedurally cleared:"

Below that you will see that you can call the method with the @st.cache_data decoration calling clear()

Example

```
@st.cache_data
```

def fetch_and_clean_data(_db_connection, num_rows):
# Fetch data from _db_connection here, and then clean it up.
return data

Can be cleared specifically using:

```
fetch_and_clean_data.clear()
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, not sure why. Would be great though :D

This is my error, i don't have time to dive into it right now:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.streamlit/cache'

notable mention, im running this from a docker container based on this image: python:3.8.17-slim-bookworm

Comment: @XiB if you are using the Streamlit command and getting that error it suggests that the Streamlit app does not have access to the file it needs. I'm not so great with Docker so this error would make a good start to a post asking the community Docker experts. They should be able to tell you how to build this with the right permissions to allow it to run properly.

Did you follow directions from Streamlit when creating the docker container? https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/deploy/docker